# how do make my website resize automatically when the screen resolution changes?

Tags: css, resolution

when i use my website on a resolution that is not 1920x1080 it zooms in so i have to scroll left and right to view the full content. how do i make the website resize to fit the resolution and display correctly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">
    <meta name="dcterms.created" content="Fri, 24 Oct 2014 20:29:09 GMT">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="description" content="The villages of East and West Runton are situated between Sheringham and Cromer on the North Norfolk Coast, UK">
    <meta name="keywords" content="East Runton, West Runton, Sheringham, Cromer, North Norfolk Coast,UK, Village, England, Parish Council">
    <title>Home</title>
 <style>

body {
width: auto;
min-width: 10240px;
height:100%;
margin-left: 0 auto;
margin-right: 0  auto;
display: block;
}
</style>

    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
 <style> 
 

#cssmenu {
  background: #f96e5b;
  width: 1404px;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  padding:0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  zoom: 1;
  width:100%
}
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0%;
  height: 0%;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#cssmenu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul li {
  float: right;
  
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu ul li a {
  color: #000000 ;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: color .25s;
  -moz-transition: color .25s;
  -ms-transition: color .25s;
  -o-transition: color .25s;
  transition: color .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover {
  color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: 19px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: .5;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: #333333;
  -webkit-transition: width .25s;
  -moz-transition: width .25s;
  -ms-transition: width .25s;
  -o-transition: width .25s;
  transition: width .25s;
}
#cssmenu ul li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a {
  color: #333333;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
  width: 100%;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu.align-right li:last-child > a:after {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:first-child a:after {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 100%) {
  #cssmenu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fb998c;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li.last > a,
  #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a {
    border: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>

<style>


.heading1 {
width:1400px;
height:120px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
padding:0;
border: 4px solid #fb998c;
}


 #box1 {
width:1400px;
height:1000px;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
padding:0;
border: 4px solid #fb998c;
}

ul > li
{ 
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  height:30px;
}

ul > li .flyout_container
{
  position:absolute;
  top:30px; /* this is the LI's height*/
  left:0;
  display:none;
}

ul > li:hover .flyout_container
{
  display:block;
}



    #east_runton{ /* The following CSS rules are optional. */
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:120px;   
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  float:left;
    }   
  
 

    #west_runton{ /* The following CSS rules are optional. */
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:120px;   
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  float:right;
  margin-top: -101.51px;
 }
 
 #title {margin-right: 160px; 
 margin-top: 2.5%;}
   
   
   #menubar2 {
   width:400px;
   margin-left:auto; 
   margin-right:auto;
   }
   
   #subheading { font-size: 130%;
   font-weight:bold;}
   
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,b, u, i, center,dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,fieldset, form, label, legend,table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,time, mark, audio, video { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; font-size: 100%; font: inherit; vertical-align: baseline;}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block;}
ol, ul { list-style: none;}blockquote, q { quotes: none;}blockquote:before, blockquote:after,q:before, q:after { content: ''; content: none;}table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;}
   
   #marqueetext {
    padding-top: 45px;
   }
   
   #marqueeimage {
    float: left;
   }
   
   #text2 {
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
   }
   
   #imgright {
    float:right;
   }
   
   #imgleft {
    float:left;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
   }
   </style>


    
  </head>
  
  <body> 
 <div class="heading1">
 
        <div id="east_runton">
    <img src="images/east_runton/1.jpg" height="120" alt="Slide 1" />
    <img src="images/east_runton/2.jpg" height="120" alt="Slide 2" />
    <img src="images/east_runton/3.jpg" height="120" alt="Slide 3" />    
    <img src="images/east_runton/4.jpg" height="120" alt="Slide 4" />
           </div>  
  <script src="slideShow.js"></script>
  
  <div id="title">
  <br /><div style="margin-top: -100px" "margin-right: 40px"> <h1 id="heading" align="center"><font color="black"><font face="Century Gothic"><font size="10"><br />East and West Runton<br /> </font size></font color></h1> 
    <p id="subheading" align="center"><font face="Century Gothic"><b>Welcome to East and West Runton's parish web site. East and West Runton are villages in North Norfolk.</b></p> </div> </font face>
     </div>       
     <div id="west_runton">
    <img src="images/west_runton/1.jpg" height="120" alt="Slide 1" />
    <img src="images/west_runton/2.jpg" height="120" alt="Slide 2" />
    <img src="images/west_runton/3.jpg" height="120" alt="Slide 3" />    
    <img src="images/west_runton/4.jpg" height="120" alt="Slide 4" />
           </div>  
  <script src="slideShow2.js"></script>
   
    </div>
 
   
  
<br />
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
  <li class='active'>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="parish_council_information.html">Parish Council information</a>
      <div class="flyout_container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="somepage_subpage">Parish council minutes</a>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="somepage_subpage">Agenda</a>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="somepage_subpage">Annual report</a>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="somepage_subpage">Publication scheme</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <li><a href="whats_on.html">What's on </a></li>
  <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
  <li><a href="churches.html">Churches</a></li>
  <li><a href="churches.html">Newsletter</a></li>
  <li><a href="villiage_halls_and_social_clubs.html">Village Halls and Social Clubs</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>  
  <div id="menubar2">
  <li><a href="business_in_runtons.html">Business in Runtons</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact_us.html">Contact us</a></li>
 </div>
</ul> 
</div>

<br />


<div id="box1"><font face="Century Gothic"><font size="+1">
<marquee><img id="marqueeimage" src="images/quality_parish_council.jpg"><div id="marqueetext">Provided by Runton Parish Council - Proud to be a Quality Council</div></marquee>

<br /><br />
<div id="text2"> <font size="+2">
<img src="images/countrywalks.jpg" alt="Country Walks, North Norfolk, UK" id="imgright" WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="225"><p>The
    villages of East and West Runton are situated between Sheringham and Cromer one mile apart
    on the North Norfolk Coast. With quiet unspoilt beaches, miles of footpaths, bridleways
    and commons with benches to relax on.</p>
    <p>There are car parks in both villages. In East Runton situated on the cliff top at Beach
    Road the car park is a &#147;Pay and Display&#148;.</p>
    <p>At West Runton situated on the A149 at the east end of the village, the car park is
    provided by the Parish Council and is free. There is also parking at the cliff top which
    carries a small charge.</p>
    <br />
    
  <p><img src="images/westruntonbeach.jpg" alt="West Runton Beach, North Norfolk, UK" id="imgleft" WIDTH="300" HEIGHT="225">There are large friendly caravan sites in both villages and ample camping facilities.</p><p>The villages have a good variety of thriving shops from which fresh
    produce is available, including camping equipment and outdoor clothing shops, butchers and
    family-run small supermarkets. Post office at West Runton.</p>
    <p>East Runton boasts two public houses, a club and restaurants and a sports ground. At
    West Runton, there is a public house and a large hotel with a nine-hole golf course, a
    beach café and a restaurant in the village street. Buses are frequent through both
    villages and there is a railway station at West Runton.<br>
    </p>
</div></font size>

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Many thanks in advance for any help given :)

Comment: Have a look @ `media queries`, `min-width` and `max-width`

Comment: Always consider Googling first. The exact query `how do make my website resize automatically when the screen resolution changes?` turns up plenty of results.

Answer (score 10):

Using percentages is one way to create a responsive web page but the better way is by using Media Queries.

Take a look at CSS3 [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

They are exactly what you need. All you need to do is specify some maximum or minimum screen dimensions in your case for each media-query. This way, you can design how your site looks on mobile devices, tablets, computers, etc. and they need not all be the same!

Something that looks good on a big screen like that of a computer need not necessarily look good on a mobile device but using media query, you can design separate versions for both devices!

For example, you execute some CSS only for desktop computers using `min-width`

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) { /*The following CSS runs only for displays with a width (in pixels) of more than 800px*/
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) { /*The following CSS runs only for displays with a width (in pixels) of less than 800px*/
    body {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
```

This way, your webpage looks different on desktop computers and looks different on mobile devices and tablets.

Also, see [this](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) great link.