# How do I make my website change size for different screen sizes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently updating my website and I would like everything to automatically change size to fit browsers, mobile and desktop alike, while keeping the same ratio.

What is the best way to do this?

I've tried several methods but haven't managed to get any working, the pictures at the bottom of the page and the javascript at the top are causing the biggest problems.

I'd prefer a html/css option, but if there's a better way through javascript I'm fine with that.

Here is link to my subdomain I'm using for testing:

http://www.beta.trinity-international.com/

Thanks!

Comment: Did you have a look at [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)? It's a css framework that will help you create responsive websites.

Comment: Use twitter bootstrap. That's the easiest way to make your pages responsive.  http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do make my website resize automatically when the screen resolution changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262385/how-do-make-my-website-resize-automatically-when-the-screen-resolution-changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go with RWD (Responsive Web Design) approach using CSS3 media queries.

**Media query:**
Media query is a CSS technique introduced in CSS3.
It uses the @media rule to include a block of CSS properties only if a certain condition is true.

**Syntax**
@media (min-width: 700px) { ... }

**Reference :**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

**Responsive frameworks :**

There are some frameworks that can be used for creating RWD.

- Twitter Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/
- Foundation http://foundation.zurb.com/
- Skeleton http://getskeleton.com/

Answer (score 1):

Some things to keep in mind for responsive web design

**Viewport:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

A `<meta>` viewport element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

**Media query:**

Media query is a CSS technique introduced in CSS3.

It uses the @media rule to include a block of CSS properties only if a certain condition is true.

For example if you want your website with different sizes for differnt screens :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
        html, body {                 
                margin-left:2%;
                margin-right:2%;                 
    }
 }
@media only screen and (min-width:1501px) {
html, body {
            margin-left:5%;
            margin-right:5%;
    }
}
```

This does not change size but just the margin that increases for bigger screen sizes.

For more explanation on responsive check this link [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp)