# what is the name of this tech to start searching for?

Tags: android, google-chrome, web

this website https://growthhackers.com/growth-studies I opened it from my android mobile using chrome, then I chose "add to home screen" to quickly get back to it. I noticed something, the icon opens just like a mobile app, not in a chrome window. When I press a link inside, the logo of growth hackers animate as a sign of loading just like mobile apps. so what is this exactly?

PS. Excuse my limited knowledge of programming. I just want to know what is the name of this just to search and learn more about it :)

Comment: Your smartphone or tablet’s home screen isn’t just for apps. Whatever platform you’re using, you can pin your favorite websites to your home screen so you can quickly access them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/progressive-web-apps

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the *web link* in question is loading the **mobile version of the website**. Thus it seems as if you are opening a mobile app. I reckon, while building a website you can make a mobile version of the same by making coding a dynamic resolution, so it aligns its interface with the mobile device screen.

If you somehow end up building a website and would want to implement the same, you may refer to:

1. [How do make my website resize automatically when the screen resolution changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262385/how-do-make-my-website-resize-automatically-when-the-screen-resolution-changes)
2. [Adjusting your websites to fit all types of resolution using HTML and CSS](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/762201/Adjusting-your-websites-to-fit-all-types-of-resolu)
3. [Responsive Web Layouts for Mobile Screens: Intro, Tips and Examples](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-for-mobile-screens/)

Moreover the loading animation and all can also be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

[o_O's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6611487/) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45539126/8355619) is basically describing how to create a mobile version of a website more than the feature you described in my opinion so this is probably more what you're after.

This isn't necessarily a Google Chrome feature from memory although for the Google Chrome documentation on that feature please find attached the link to the specs.

It's all about including a META tag or two in your HTML's head section.
I believe you need these meta tags specifically:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

and additionally, you can change the colours of the navigation bar in Chrome by changing the theme-color meta tag and the content attribute.

```
<!-- WebKit/Chrome/Blink browsers? -->
<meta name="theme-color" content="#CAAF6A">
<!-- Windows Phone -->
<meta name="msapplication-navbutton-color" content="#CAAF6A">
<!-- iOS Safari -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

I've read a few of the specs from Google about this feature but the one that appears to be the most clear seems to be this one:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/

tl;dr
Google 'Web App Manifest' additionally, try and use the docs I've linked above